# Always at the bottom if id='3' (use `ORDER BY` in MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
id
----
0
2
1
3
7
1
6
3
1
```

I want to sort the `id` value in descending order by using `ORDER BY` in MySQL.

But if `id` value equals `3`, always put it to the bottom.

The result will be like:

```
id
----
7
6
2
1
1
1
0
3
3
```

How should I do?

My try:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` ORDER BY CASE WHEN id='3' THEN ??? END, id DESC
```

What should the question marks be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Tim's answer I would like to play around with boolean value:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    `table`
ORDER BY (id = 3), id DESC
```

---

Since MySQL `boolean` expression resolves into `0/1` so that we can play with that in this particular scenario.

Look when the `id is equal to 3` then the order by looks like `ORDER BY 1, <id> DESC`.

And for any other id other than **3** it looks like `ORDER BY 0, <id> DESC`

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 2):

Order first by a `CASE` expression forcing id values of 3 to the bottom, then order descending by the id itself.

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         id DESC
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id = '3', id DESC
```